# Grabbing last frame from cv::VideoCapture

Tags: ios, opencv, video-capture

How can I access the last frame of a video using cv::VideoCapture?

In OpenCVViewController.h:

```
@interface OpenCVViewController : UIViewController {

    cv::VideoCapture *_videoCapture;
    cv::Mat _lastFrame;

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *_previewLayer;
    UIView *_videoPreviewView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *captureButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *videoPreviewView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;

- (IBAction)capture:(id)sender;

@end
```

And in OpenCVViewController.mm:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _videoCapture = new cv::VideoCapture;
    if (!_videoCapture->open(CV_CAP_AVFOUNDATION)) {
        NSLog(@"Open video camera failed");
    }

    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    CALayer *viewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    _previewLayer.frame = _videoPreviewView.bounds;
    [_videoPreviewView.layer addSublayer:_previewLayer];
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDeviceInput defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        NSLog(@"Error opening camera: %@", error);
    }

    [session addInput:input];
    [session startRunning];

}


- (IBAction)capture:(id)sender {

    _captureButton.enabled = NO;

    if (_videoCapture && _videoCapture->grab()) {
        (*_videoCapture) >> _lastFrame;          //Line is hit
    }
    else {
        NSLog("Failed to grab frame");
    }
}
```

When the capture button is pressed, I want to grab the last frame in the videoCapture and save the data into _lastFrame.  Using the method shown above, in the IBAction, _last frame is empty.

Is there another way to grab a frame and use _lastFrame to process the image later on?

Thanks in advance!  Using iOS 6 with opencv2 framework

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried using retrieve() instead of grab()?

Comment: I hadn't tried retrive, but I think that worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: Although it's grabbing the first thing it sees, not the frame seen when the button is tapped

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [VideoCapture::read](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read), which combines grab() and retrieve().

Also, I think both read() and retrieve() return a reference to the VideoCapture Buffer, so you'll need to use cvCloneImage() to manipulate the frame.